# Java - How to invoke a function which has infinite running loop multiple times with different class objects?

Tags: java

I am having a class (say `UDPData`) which has a method (say `getData()`). That function has while loop running in infinite loop to keep listening to a UDP Port. Now I want to execute this method using different objects of the class (`UDPData`) but first method call with `obj1` is getting held and no further calls using different objects are made.

I want to call that method multiple times without any call getting stuck and holding back other calls.

Sample Code:

```
class UDPData {
    public String getData() {
        while(true) {
            // Code Goes here...
        }
    }
}

// Method Calls like this
UDPData obj1 = new UDPData();
obj1.getData();

UDPData obj2 = new UDPData();
obj2.getData();

UDPData obj3 = new UDPData();
obj3.getData();
```

Sample Code will really help.

Comment: You'll need to use a different `Thread` for each call to `getData()`.

Comment: You can use threads, each `objx.getData()` in an own thread.

Comment: The way you're currently running it, the code gets stuck inside the infinite `while` loop - after all, it only does one thing at a time. Look into learning about [concurrency in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), or How To Tell Java To Do More Than One Thing At Once.

Comment: @Zephyr are you asking me to implement Runnable and use Thread to start it?

Comment: Look into the link that @GreenCloakGuy posted to learn how to do more than one thing at a time in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Client/server works (=is coded) a bit different.

The server would do something very vaguely like:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
for (;;) {
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // Await a client request
    executorService.startWorker(clientSocket);
}
```

(This code is is taken from a non-UDP example; you probably are already using `DatagramSocket` for UDP.)

That is a loop waiting for an UDP message and then dispatching it to a new Thread.

This keeps the server responsive.

However everything is asynchrone, like UDP itself actually. The workers need to construct greater data constructs by *queues* and such.